# Why do I get this error: "This feature (Digital Goods) is not supported."?

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to use PayPal's AdaptivePayments API with Digital Goods but I get the above error when I'm redirected to PayPal's site for confirmation. I call the PAY function using their Java SDK, receive a success message with a PAY-KEY and redirect the user for confirmation, but I always get this message. Anyone has any idea why?

To see this happening you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERID=""
PASSWORD=""
SIGNATURE=""

APPID="APP-80W284485P519543T"

RECEIVER="test@test.com"
AMOUNT="100.00"

CANCELURL="http://example.com/cancel"
RETURNURL="http://example.com/return"

RESULT=$(curl -s --insecure -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: $USERID" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: $PASSWORD" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: $SIGNATURE" -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: $APPID" https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay -d "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&actionType=PAY&receiverList.receiver(0).email=$RECEIVER&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=$AMOUNT&memo=Parallel payment example.&cancelUrl=$CANCELURL&returnUrl=$RETURNURL;")

echo $RESULT
```

After getting the key, copy it and go to this url:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=PLACE_THE_KEY_HERE

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got that error because I was redirecting the user to the wrong url. Should be: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=PLACE_KEY_HERE